# Google Play Services Leaderboards not working(Trying to show UI while waiting for a result from an existing UI)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I have a problem implementing the Leaderboards. Login works just fine, but when I try to show the leaderboards I get :

"Trying to show UI while waiting for a result from an existing UI. Please ensure that OnActivityResulty is forwarded to the Games C++ SDK from your Java activity. See android.suport.h for more details."

This is my method for showing(attached on a button) :

```
public void ShowLeaderboardsUI()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI("myString");
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem in a Native C++ app

Answer (score 0):

2 things you can try as per this [github forum](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1931):

> 1. Downgrade to 0.9.40
> 2. Add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml
>
> < activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity"
>               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
>   />

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I added that line into the manifest but no success :(. And regarding the downgrade, I can't find anywhere the 0.9.40 version, the last one I find(besides the 0.9.50) is 0.9.25, and thats too old, can you help me with this ?